# MPMoviePlayer only playing sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayer

Trying to put my video in a custom view within a UITableViewCell.

videoView is a UIView:

The following is when the cell is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FeedCustomCell *cell = [[FeedCustomCell alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_videoPathString];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    CGRect previewFrame = CGRectMake(cell.videoView.frame.origin.x,
                                     cell.videoView.frame.origin.y,
                                     cell.videoView.frame.size.width,
                                     cell.videoView.frame.size.height);

    moviePlayer.view.frame = previewFrame;
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];

    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

This is my cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedCustomCell";
    FeedCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _usernameString];
    cell.createdDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _createdString];

    return cell;
}
```

I am only adding something to cell.videoView when the cell is selected. Am I doing this wrong?

Video is playing with sound, but no visual.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Try this:

```
[self.view.contentView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```